# Question regarding creation of an absolute value function in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am currently just starting out working through Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programming, and in a section it is going over the creation of an absolute value function in Scheme (takes a value, and returns its absolute value).

I am following exactly how the book does the function:

```
(define (abs x)
  (cond ((< x 0) (- x))
        (else x)))
```

Unfortunately, this is not providing the desired result as the book says.  Instead of returning the absolute value, it just returns the value.  For example, I type in -5, the function returns -5.

If it is of any help, I am using the BiwaScheme Interpreter (0.6.4).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: no, the code is right. I just tried it at https://www.biwascheme.org/ and after pasting the definition from your question, `(abs -5)` does return 5 as it should there at the REPL.

Comment: Huh, thank you.  I wonder what's going on... for reference you can access the shell I'm using here: https://repl.it/@blasphemousjohn/Practice

Comment: it works: https://repl.it/repls/CarelessPunyConnections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function, enclose its name in parentheses together with any arguments you wish to supply it with. Example,

```
> (abs -5)
5
```

Of course if you just type `-5` you are *not* calling any functions, `abs` in particular, with it:

```
> -5
-5
```

The numeric value is just returned as is, as no function call is indicated.

Comment: Ahhh!  I was calling 'abs -5' without the parentheses.  My bad, improper syntax. Thank you

Comment: welcome. always include your program code, test call and output/error message, in your questions. :) :)